# how to use GPU in kaggle_python docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, kaggle

I install kaggle_python docker image from this tutorial：
http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/02/05/how-to-get-started-with-data-science-in-containers/
this image is perfect but I don't know how to use GPU in it. anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please provide the code you're struggling with in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia has released a docker runtime that allows docker containers to access their host GPU. Assuming the image you're running has the CUDA libraries built in, you ought to be able to [install nvidia-docker as per their instructions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker), then just launch a container using `docker run --runtime=nvidia ...`

[There's an FAQ for using nvidia-dockers](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki) if you run into other roadblocks. I haven't done this myself, but lots of issues are probably going to be specific to how you installed the drivers and cuda libraries on your particular machine. You may also have to [modify the image](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-do-i-have-to-install-in-my-container-images) to include any necessary CUDA libraries if they aren't already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the CUDA branch (link: https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/tree/cuda)? If so, all the infrastructure for the GPUs should already be set up and ready to go. Otherwise, you're going to have to do the setup yourself. :)